# How to make finite loop in Arduino

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I'm a beginner in coding and especially in Arduino. I have been doing many projects, but I came across a problem. I can't seem to be able to figure out how to make a finite loop. I'm looking at something like a `while` loop which stops after four times around. Here is where it will be implemented to give you a better idea of what I'm looking for.

```
#include <Servo.h>

int thumbPin = 2;
int ndxPin = 3;
int midPin = 4;
int rngPin = 5;
int pnkyPin = 6;

Servo thumb;
Servo index;
Servo middle;
Servo ring;
Servo pinky;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  thumb.attach(thumbPin);
  index.attach(ndxPin);
  middle.attach(midPin);
  ring.attach(rngPin);
  pinky.attach(pnkyPin);
}
void loop() {
  /* I want this code in the comment to be ran four times, then continued on to the code after
  thumb.write(0);
  delay(20);
  thumb.write(0);
  index.write(0);
  middle.write(0);
  ring.write(0);
  pinky.write(0);

  thumb.write(150);
  index.write(150);
  middle.write(150);
  ring.write(150);
  pinky.write(150);
  */
  thumb.write(0);
  index.write(0);
  pinky.write(0);

  middle.write(0);
  thumb.write(150);
  pinky.write(150);
}
```

Comment: Are you coding in C, C++ or C#? Please don't spam the tags but use only the one relevant to your question.

Comment: Arduino is neither of the given languages! Do not add tags for unrelated languages.

Comment: It looks a lot like the stated languages, and I know the basic syntax (while, for, if...else, etc.)  is almost - the same.

Comment: Besides, the more the tags the sooner the response. :)

Comment: You will need to put a `delay` after `pinky.write(0);` otherwise after setting the servos to `0` you will inmediately set them to `150`.

Answer (score 7):

You want a for loop: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/For

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  thumb.write(0);
  delay(20);
  thumb.write(0);
  index.write(0);
  middle.write(0);
  ring.write(0);
  pinky.write(0);

  thumb.write(150);
  index.write(150);
  middle.write(150);
  ring.write(150);
  pinky.write(150);
}
```